# Running builds from pull-tester on windows results in crash on startup

Tags: bitcoind, compiling

What to do to run them on Windows 7? Just using a normal installation, x64, where normal bitcoind.exe, downloaded from bitcoin.org runs fine...
The builds which crash are from http://jenkins.bluematt.me/pull-tester/

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but what I got is "I downloaded some potentially modified version of the Bitcoin daemon from some arbitrary website, why isn't it working?". If I understood that correctly, I am afraid you should probably try to talk to the person that hosts it. – Should I, on the other hand, misunderstand your question, you might want to be a bit more verbose about the origin of the file.

Comment: To my understanding, Matt is one of the main developers of Bitcoin. The pull-tester is the main mechanism for automatic testing of pull requests, it is used in the official bitcoin github, it has been referenced from foundation's articles, reports from it are added automatically to every pull request in the official repository. Pretty far from "some arbitrary website" don't you think? ) I am going to try to contact him, but I figured that Bitcoin developers have more important stuff to do than such seemingly basic questions, I thought there was some lib missing or something...

Comment: Well, then I guess we landed in the "on the other hand" case. – I wasn't aware that *TheBlueMatt* is Matt Corallo.

Comment: Is this pull mechanism bitcoin-specific or is it used by other programmers for other projects? If so it may be better suited for Stack Overflow or similar. If it's a Bitcoin-specific process then it definitely belongs here.